# assign the value stored in a variable as the name of an arraylist

Tags: java

Is there a way by which the name of an arraylist can be assigned a name stored in a variable.  The requirement is like i need to run a loop in which i need to create an arraylist whose name will be the value of the variable which stores the loop count.

Comment: A brief example would be nice. I can't work out if you want to store the name of a class that will be dynamically created etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't think that might be possible. What you might want to do is create a [Map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Map.html) whose key would be name that you're referring to and the value would be an ArrayList object

Answer (score 0):

1. ArrayLists does not have names. You could have a named variable (or many actually) referencing an ArrayList, but the list itself knows nothing about this.
2. Even if it was possible to create dynamic variables, with names based on the value of some other variable, it wouldn't work with a counter, since numbers aren't valid variable names.
3. And, even if it was possible to create dynamic variables with numbers as a name, it wouldn't work because any variable declared within a loop is out of scope for any portion of code outside the loop body itself.

Like it's being said here, use a map to create a link between some counter value and an ArrayList:

```
  final Map<Integer, List<String>> myMap = new HashMap<Integer, List<String>>();

  for (int i = 0; i < something; i++=) {
      myMap.put(i, new ArrayList<String>());
  }
```